# nest.js Error: Only one plugin can implement renderLandingPage

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, prisma

I`m using nest.js graphql prisma.
When I run the npm run start:dev command, I get the following error.

error

> /node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/ApolloServer.ts:471 throw
> Error('Only one plugin can implement renderLandingPage.');
> ^ Error: Only one plugin can implement renderLandingPage.

```
app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault } from 'apollo-server-core';
import { DonationsModule } from './donations/donations.module';
import { ApolloDriverConfig, ApolloDriver } from '@nestjs/apollo';

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault()],
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
    }),
    DonationsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 6):

As per [NestJs Docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start#getting-started-with-graphql--typescript):

> To use Apollo Sandbox instead of the graphql-playground as a GraphQL IDE for local development, use the following configuration:

So you must insert inside the `.forRoot({})` code the following element: `playground: false,`.

So your code will be:

```ts
app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault } from 'apollo-server-core';
import { DonationsModule } from './donations/donations.module';
import { ApolloDriverConfig, ApolloDriver } from '@nestjs/apollo';

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      playground: false, // this line is the only change in your code
      plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault()],
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
    }),
    DonationsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```