# How To Config Apollo Sandbox for GraphQL in NestJS?

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

I am trying to use Apollo Sandbox for GraphQL in NestJs since I had to upgrade to apollo/server from apollo-server-express.

I added the configuration like described in the [NestJS docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start#apollo-sandbox). I also checked the [Apollo Docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/plugin/landing-pages/#graphql-playground-landing-page).

My setup is now like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71187627/nest-js-error-only-one-plugin-can-implement-renderlandingpage).

Here is what I use:

```
"@apollo/server": "^4.7.3",
"@apollo/server-plugin-landing-page-graphql-playground": "^4.0.1",
"@nestjs/apollo": "^11.0.6",
"@nestjs/graphql": "^11.0.6"
```

Now when I access the playground it says:

> Welcome to Apollo Server
> Apollo Sandbox cannot be loaded; it appears that you might be offline.

In the console, I see a bunch of script loading errors such as

> Refused to load the image 'https://apollo-server-landing-page.cdn.apollographql.com/_latest/assets/favicon.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".
>
> graphql:22 Refused to load the image 'https://apollo-server-landing-page.cdn.apollographql.com/_latest/assets/favicon.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".
>
> graphql:1 Refused to load the script 'https://embeddable-sandbox.cdn.apollographql.com/_latest/embeddable-sandbox.umd.production.min.js?runtime=%40apollo%2Fserver%404.7.4' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
>
> graphql:71 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-OK7pAH5PWuMz0B3Z+8KJD+AVvhgLxb2X4W00TmJw2M8='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

> Refused to load the image 'https://apollo-server-landing-page.cdn.apollographql.com/_latest/assets/favicon.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".
>
> graphql:1 Refused to load manifest from 'https://apollo-server-landing-page.cdn.apollographql.com/_latest/manifest.json' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'
> Note that 'manifest-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I tried to change the config options like described [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-playground/issues/1283#issuecomment-1292153300) but without success.

Did anyone experience the same behaviour and solve it?

I tried to set the options as described in the docs but it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that this was a configuration issue in NestJS's `main.ts` related to content security policy:

```js
app.use(helmet({
  crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,
  contentSecurityPolicy: {
    directives: {
      imgSrc: [`'self'`, 'data:', 'apollo-server-landing-page.cdn.apollographql.com'],
      scriptSrc: [`'self'`, `https: 'unsafe-inline'`],
      manifestSrc: [`'self'`, 'apollo-server-landing-page.cdn.apollographql.com'],
      frameSrc: [`'self'`, 'sandbox.embed.apollographql.com'],
    },
  },
}));
```

see https://docs.nestjs.com/security/helmet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault

```
 import {ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault} from '@apollo/server/plugin/landingPage/default';

 GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      playground: false,
      //use apollo playground
      plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault()],
    }),
```

mentioned in official docs
https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start#apollo-sandbox